# How to wait for user input on JavaFX application thread without using showAndWait?

Tags: javafx, javafx-9

I'd like to pause the execution of a method on the JavaFX application thread and wait until the user does interaction with the UI. It's important not to freeze the UI.

Example:

```
Button start = ...
Button resume = ...

start.setOnAction(evt -> {
     System.out.println("starting");
     start.setDisable(true);
     System.out.println("please press resume button.");
     pause();
     System.out.println("done");
     start.setDisable(false);
});

resume.setOnAction(evt -> resume());
```

How should I implement the `pause()` and `resume()` methods?
The execution of the event handler should wait at `pause();` call until the user presses the `resume` button and the `resume` method is called.

Comment: Is it really required to 'pause' within the method execution? Just finish the method instead of calling 'pause()' and do the rest of the work in the resume button's action handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so by using [`Platform.enterNestedEventLoop`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#enterNestedEventLoop(java.lang.Object)) to pause the execution of the event handler and [`Platform.exitNestedEventLoop`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#exitNestedEventLoop(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) (available since JavaFX 9) to resume the execution:

```
private final Object PAUSE_KEY = new Object();

private void pause() {
    Platform.enterNestedEventLoop(PAUSE_KEY);
}

private void resume() {
    Platform.exitNestedEventLoop(PAUSE_KEY, null);
}
```

`Platform.enterNestedEventLoop` returns when `Platform.exitNestedEventLoop` is called with the same parameter passed as first argument.

Comment: Is `Platform.enterNestedEventLoop` idempotent, or do calls accumulate? Specifically, if `Platform.enterNestedEventLoop(...)` is called, and then called from the nested loop with the same parameter, does the first call to `Platform.exitNestedEventLoop` (with the same parameter) release both blocks, or does it only release the block in the nested event loop (requiring a second call to release the original block)?

Comment: @James_D It's not allowed to use the same key with `enterNestedEventLoop` more than once before the nested loop is exited. A `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown if you try, see [javadoc: *IllegalArgumentException - if the specified key is associated with a nested event loop that has not yet returned*](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/application/Platform.html#enterNestedEventLoop-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: And before Java9? :)

Comment: @user1803551 It's a javafx 9 question. There are similar methods available in previous javafx versions, but they recide in the `com.sun` packages that are not recommended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running JFX 8 where I have the similar feature in the Toolkit class.

```
Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(obj);
```

and

```
Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(obj);
```

Have not looked at the JFX 9 source, but my bet is that the Platform methods are simply shortcuts to the same.

Comment: It's likely a shortcut, but always remember: Don't use private API for production because they have every single right to remove a private API and replace with something else, without telling anyone about the change. So at any point they can remove `Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(Object)` and make `Platform.enterNestedEventLoop()` call some other private stuff that does the same thing.