# Create modal dialog from scratch

Tags: java, javafx, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create my own implementation for an overlay dialog that opens up when the user clicks a button. The code you see below works perfectly fine but is not that pretty. I'm searching for an implementation where I don't have to create a Thread for each dialog I create. Is there any way to acchieve this?

I've been browsing through various Java source files like `JOptionPane` and `JDialog` to figure out what they do in order to block the thread until the user closes the dialog, but I didn't manage to understand it. Additionally I tried various code snippets including the `EventQueue` like for example `EventQueue.invokeLater` or `EventQueue.invokeAndWait`.

```
// MainViewController.java

@FXML
private void handleServerButton(ActionEvent evt){
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        if (serverD.showDialog(overlay) == Dialog.OK_OPTION){
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ABORT");
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

// Dialog.java

public int showDialog(Pane parent) {
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    this.result.set(NONE);

    approveButton.setDefaultButton(true);
    abortButton.setCancelButton(true);
    container.setVisible(true);
    parent.setVisible(true);

    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex){ }

    approveButton.setDefaultButton(false);
    abortButton.setCancelButton(false);
    container.setVisible(false);
    parent.setVisible(false);

    return result.get();
}

@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Integer> observable, Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) {
    if (newValue != NONE)
        latch.countDown();
}
```

This is what it looks like (please note: the overlay dialog is not a window itself but rather a pane within the main window):

Final Result

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but why not use a second `Stage` or `PopupWindow` for this purpose? They all inherit the `Window` class which defines the `showAndWait()` method, which is exactually what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does that work for a pane used as a "window"? Because I would like to integrate the dialogs into the main window (I will add a screenshot to the description above).

Comment: The `PopupWindow` can be configured to act as a tooltip. In fact the `Tooltip` class uses the `PopuoWindow` class (check the source codes if you want to see the example).

Comment: Thank you very much n247s, I will try it out. I also added screenshot as I mentioned before.

Comment: I am unsure as to why you need a thread at all.

Comment: @Sedrick because otherwise my UI freezes (the latch is there to block the thread until the changed method is invoked outside and the latch is counted down)

Comment: Either I am not understanding your problem or you have complicated something that should be pretty straight forward. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a modal window in JavaFX 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486731/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-javafx-2-1)

Comment: @Sedrick maybe I left out too much of the information needed. Please have a look at the [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvThf.png) that should make everything clearer :)

Comment: Have a look at the possible duplicate.

Comment: Have you seen the [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) library? Specifically, its [JFXDialog component](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix#components)? Anyway, `JOptionPane` and `JDialog` are Swing objects, you should be looking at JavaFX objects such as `Dialog` and `Window` (note they can't be embedded in a scene). And you don't need to use another thread to wait for user input; what you need is a nested event loop. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369046/how-to-wait-for-user-input-on-javafx-application-thread-without-using-showandwai).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Alert` and `Dialog` documentation. Both provide functionality similar to what you want, and both can be customised if they don't quite match your use case.

Quick example:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("title");
alert.setContent("content");
...
// More customisation available, read the docs
alert.show();. // Or showAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deriving a `Dialog` class from `Stage` and implementing the logic there. The only thing that is left, is to extract the values from the controls of the view controller. But I already noticed that the dialog is passed as a Window through the `ActionEvent` - so that should be a minor issue.

```
public class Dialog extends Stage {

    public static int OK_OPTION = 0;

    public static int ABORT_OPTION = -1;

    private int result;

    public Dialog(Scene parent, String url) throws IOException{
        super(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(url));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X")){
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;");
        }
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setScene(scene);

        initOwner(parent.getWindow());

        double titlebar = parent.getWindow().getHeight() - parent.getHeight();
        setX(parent.getWindow().getX());
        setY(parent.getWindow().getY() + titlebar + 50);
    }

    public int showDialog(){
        showAndWait();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better solution, you might want to call `initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL)` to get the 'event blocking behavior' of the parent window, if that is what you are going for. Another option is to listen to the focused property of your `Dialog` class, and autohide the window when it is unfocused.